# Can LibreOffice be told to enter some kind of "focus mode"?

Tags: libreoffice

I'm sitting here trying to go through this massive document that I have written, and it's Hell.

I keep wishing that I could somehow easily enter a mode in which the entire document, except for the immediate sentence (and perhaps the last and next sentence), dims down so that the relevant part, where the cursor is, is fully "lit", allowing me to mentally block out the rest as I'm trying to slowly "chew through" it.

I know that I can zoom. It's not the same thing.

Does LibreOffice have such a mode?

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + Shift J puts you in fullscreen mode